# $ a(n,K) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} i^K a(i,K) a(n-i,K) $?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, generating-functions, closed-form

Consider

$$ a(1) = 1 $$

$$ a(2) = a(1) a(1) = 1 $$

$$ a(3) = a(1) a(2) + 2 a(1) a(2) = 3 $$

$$ a(4) = a(1) a(3) + 2 a(2) a(2) + 3 a(3) a(1) = 14 $$

$$ a(5) = a(1) a(4) + 2 a(2) a(3) + 3 a(3) a(2) + 4 a(4) a(1) = 14 + 6 + 9 + 56 = 85 $$

$$ a(n) = 1 a(1) a(n-1) + 2 a(2) a(n-2) + 3 a(3) a(n-3) + ... $$

This recursion reminds me of Catalan numbers.
Also factorial numbers and fibonacci(2 n) have similar recursions.

Im not sure if this is “ combinatorics “ or “ calculus “ like the Catalan Numbers.

I wonder If there is a closed form.
It seems to grow like $ \frac{n^2 n!}{5} $ but that is a very brute estimate.

—-

Slightly more general

$$ a(n,K) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} i^K a(i,K) a(n-i,K) $$

for Nonzero K is a mystery to me.

Closed form ? Accurate growth rate ( asymptotic ) ??

Is this a known generalization of Catalan Numbers ??

Comment: Multiplication of the coefficients by their indices corresponds to the application of the operator $xD=x\frac{d}{dx}$. So in this case, it is applied $k$ times to one of the factors on the right. In other words, $f(x)=(xD)^k(f(x))f(x)$, where $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

For
$$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i\, a_i\, a_{n-1} \qquad \text{with} \qquad a_1=1$$ the first numbers are
$$\{1,1,3,14,85,621,5236,49680,521721,5994155,74701055,1003125282\}$$ which correspond to sequence [$A088716$ at $OEIS$](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+3%2C+14%2C+85%2C+621%2C+5236%2C+49680%2C+521721%2C+5994155&sort=&language=&go=Search).

On this page, you will find the asymptotics
$$a(n) \sim c \, n! \, n^2, \qquad \text{where} \qquad  c=0.21795078944715106549282282244231982088... $$ proposed by Vaclav Kotesovec in 2014 which is incredibly closed to your approximation (look at $A238223$ for the decimal expansion of $c$).

A closed form does not seem to exist.

For $K>1$, I have not been able to find anything.